# I can't scrape a part of an html code (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, spyder, screen-scraping

Im trying to obtain the information table of this page https://www.binance.com/es-LA/altcoins/new of new coins at the bottom of the page. But I am having a lot of problem with that.

When I try to look for certain parts of the html code (the part that contains the table information), I obtain *NoneType* objects. I tried to look *div* by *div* but I always have the same problem at the same part.

```
Buscador = requests.get('https://www.binance.com/es-LA/altcoins/new', 'lxml')

BuscadorSopeado = bs(Buscador.text, features = 'html.parser')

BusquedaPrimero = BuscadorSopeado.find(name = 'div', attrs = {'class': "css-1t63o3e"})
```

Where type(BusquedaPrimero) = None.

If I see the previous part of the html code I have as a result a giant line:

```
IN:
BusquedaPrimero = BuscadorSopeado.find(name = 'div', attrs = {'class': "css-pcu8qt"})

OUT:    
<div class="css-pcu8qt"><style data-emotion-css="18rcfta">.css-18rcfta{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;min-width:0;overflow-wrap:break-word;font-size:24px;font-weight:600;line-height:32px;color:#1E2329;margin-bottom:64px;}@media screen and (min-width:767px){.css-18rcfta{font-size:32px;font-weight:600;line-height:40px;}}@media screen and (min-width:1023px){.css-18rcfta{font-size:40px;font-weight:600;line-height:48px;}}</style><h2 class="container__title css-18rcfta" data-bn-type="text">Principales criptoactivos por porcentaje de la capitalización total de mercado</h2><div class="sc-gtsrHT cVacoL cmc-btc-percentage-chart" id="dominance-percentage"><style data-emotion-css="1ig4gr6">.css-1ig4gr6{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;min-width:0;display:-webkit-box;display:-webkit-flex;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;width:30px;height:30px;-webkit-align-items:center;-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center;-webkit-box-pack:justify;-webkit-justify-content:space-between;-ms-flex-pack:justify;justify-content:space-between;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-top:337px;margin-bottom:337px;}</style><div class="css-1ig4gr6"><style data-emotion-css="2bc2yz animation-hqgv56">
        
*AND MORE THINGS THAT I CUT.*
```

I'm new scraping things, so I apologize if the solution is easy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you re looking for in the webpage but there is two explanations:
First the site web block your request so you should see a 404 status or 403 if this the case I suggest to add a "headers" with "user_agent" in your request
Second if you try to scrape a website that use javascript you may miss some information because sadly bs4 library can't get javascript component